# Can I back up to an SD card?

Tags: backup, sd-card

I happy accident occurred this weekend when I left my camera's USB cable at work. I discovered that I have an SD slot in my MacBook Pro.

Can I backup to an SD card using a third party back up package? I typically do a nightly local back up as a fail safe.

Comment: You can, but I wouldn't trust an SD card as far as I could spit it as far as reliability goes. Fail rate is alarmingly high.

Answer (score 1):

I use an [SanDisk Ultra miniDrive (64 GB)](http://www.sandisk.com/products/memory-cards/readers/ultra-minidrive/) for transferable storage. However, I use an external hard drive to maintain Time Machine backups.

Of note, for compatibility with Time Machine, the SD's default format (exFat) was incompatible, and I needed to use Disk Utility to reformat to Mac OS Extended (Journaled).

For for information about SD cards, [Apple provides information](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204384).